# Access denied when repeatedly create and remove the same directory

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-7

I just had a little test, and this is how I did it:
I repeatedly create and remove one directory, d:\test, for example. I did that for like 1000 times, and it always will get an error for acccessing denied for some time.

My code wrote like this:

```
TCHAR szError[MAX_PATH] = {0};
TCHAR lpszPath[MAX_PATH] = _T("d:\\test");
for(int i = 0; i != 1000; i++)
{
    if (!CreateDirectory(lpszPath, NULL))
    {
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, GetLastError(), NULL, szError, MAX_PATH, NULL);
        MessageBox(NULL, szError, _T("create directory error"), MB_OK);
        cout << i << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    SetFileAttributes(lpszPath, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL);
    if (!RemoveDirectory(lpszPath))
    {
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, GetLastError(), NULL, szError, MAX_PATH, NULL);
        MessageBox(NULL, szError, _T("remove directory error"), MB_OK);
        cout << i << endl;
        return 0;
    }   
}
```

Can anyone please tell me why this error happened and how can I avoid that error?

Comment: I wonder if directory deletion is performed lazily and sometimes isn't yet finished by the time the directory is created again.

Comment: There is both operating system caching and caching on the disk controller so you are likely correct.

Comment: If the system is still caching, how can I know that? How can I avoid the error happening?

Comment: Could easily be a process which has opened the directory in the window between creating it and deleting it, and hasn't closed it yet.  Say, an indexing service.  Regardless, I would avoid synchronous disk access functions -- they are bad smell.

Comment: @Yakk - yes an indexing service, DropBox share or virus scanner can do this. There are many others.

Answer (score 3):

See RemoveDirectory documentation;
"The RemoveDirectory function marks a directory for deletion on close. Therefore, the directory is not removed until the last handle to the directory is closed."

This means that if something manages to create a handle to the directory you remove (between creation and removal) then the directory isn't actually removed and you get your 'Access Denied',

To solve this rename the directory you want to remove before removing it.

Comment: You just saved the day!

Answer (score 0):

If this is a speed issue, you could consider using a sleep function between each create/delete.